# Is there a Simplified Chinese thesaurus file, like Moby for English?

Tags: nlp, language, text

I'm looking for a manually curated thesaurus/synonyms file for Simplified Chinese. Like the English Moby thesaurus, but in simplified Chinese. Does such a thing exist?

I'm aware that WordNet can be used to obtain synonyms, but, in English at least, it is not very comprehensive.

To clarify:

I need it to be manually/human curated, not based on statistical similarity as I am already doing cosine similarity based on a large corpus, and this is intended to be an additional check.

It needs to be an offline data file so I can use it for automatic processing.

Answer (score 2):

The following tools/ websites seems to do what you are looking for:

- [usechinese.com/Apps/Thesaurus](https://usechinese.com/Apps/Thesaurus) (also allows for searching using English input)
- [Chinese-tools](https://www.chinese-tools.com/tools/synonyms.html).
- [Chinese Synonyms Thesaurus](https://chinese.gratis/tools/synonym/)

However, if you are looking for data then maybe you can use the [following data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chatopera/Synonyms/master/synonyms/data/vocab.txt) from this project [chatopera /
Synonyms](https://github.com/chatopera/Synonyms) .

Finally, the following post: [Is there a Chinese WordNet?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/793/is-there-a-chinese-wordnet) from https://chinese.stackexchange.com seems to provide more materials/ resources related to your search, so it is worth checking.